# Building Ocean 2011 plugins with Visual Studio 11 Beta - issue with InventorNet.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ocean, petrel

I've started testing VS11 beta for building Ocean 2011 plugins.  It seems to work very well, and has enough advantages that I'm considering using it for daily work.  (We will, of course, not make production builds with VS11 before Schlumberger recommends it.)

However, there is one blocking issue:

Projects which depend on InventorNet.dll fail to build, with the following messages:

*C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1546,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "InventorNet", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.*

**CSC : fatal error CS0008: Unexpected error reading metadata from file 'c:\Program Files\Schlumberger\Petrel 2011\InventorNet.dll' -- 'Index not found.'***

I *think* the first warning is harmless, as similar warnings are emitted from other dependencies, but I can't get past the error message (in bold).  Both probably originate from stricter assembly verification in .NET 4.5 (also in beta) used by MSBuild.  Our projects target .NET 3.5.

Does anyone know if the error can be fixed with some setting or other trick, or do we need updated assemblies from Schlumberger?  (A Google search yields a few similar cases relating to VS2010, and indicates that the assembly provider does, indeed, need to rebuild the assembly to correct the issue.)

Alternatively, can someone indicate whether the issue will be remedied by Ocean 2012?

Comment: Did you try targeting x64 with your assemblies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just simply test your case for petre/ocean 2012 D9 snapshot version with OIV 9.0.0.0(for 2011, it is 8.1.2.2), it seems that it works fine(passed building with some warnings in visual studio 2011, and running OK in Petrel 2012 D9)。

Deng Feng

Answer (score 1):

Just about warnings for Ocean 2012 in VS11beta: it can be "CPU mismatch" warning if your solution has "Any CPU" target and based on top of Petrel 64 (Because Inventor's DLLs are CPU dependent). And it will be no warnings if you select 64 bit CPU target for your project.
Alex

Answer (score 0):

first warning can be eliminated by adding the following string to your .csproj file:

```
<PlatformTarget Condition=" '$(PlatformTarget)' == '' ">x86</PlatformTarget>
```

I added it inside  node, after  node